# Specify a value can be a string or null with JSON Schema

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

Hopefully this isn't obvious to others because I find the docs at https://json-schema.org/ to be lacking in finer details. I'm getting a block of JSON with some properties that can be `null` or a `string`. How do you specify, in a JSON Schema (to be parsed by Json.NET's `JsonSchema.Parse` method), that a value can be of type `null` or type `string`?

Is there something simple I'm missing like supplying an array for the type? For example;

```
"member_region": { "type": [ "string", null ] } // this throws an exception
```

Also, does anyone have a better source for JSON Schema details than json-schema.org? Where can I find a larger selection of examples? I don't want to read a big document/specification to find something that can easily be demonstrated in a 10 line example.

Comment: Source with more examples and documentation: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/ which is linked in json-schema.org

Answer (score 256, accepted):

From https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html

> The `type` keyword may either be a string or an array:
>
> - If it’s a string, it is the name of one of the basic types above.
> - If it is an array, it must be an **array of strings**, where each string is the name of one of the basic types, and each element is unique. In this case, the JSON snippet is valid if it matches *any* of the given types

The same page lists also the defined data type names, including `string` and `null`.

Try:

```
"member_region": { "type": ["string", "null"] }
```

Comment: This is an updated link to the location in the current spec: <http://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.7.6.1>

Comment: This does not work when need use patterns or other filters. null variable can not use in regex or specifics filters.

Answer (score 94):

Extending on Explosion Pills answer if you go for the array syntax:

```
"member_region": { "type": [ "string", "null" ] } // this works
```

because you are stating a type, not an example/value. You shouldn't go for:

```
 "member_region": { "type": [ "string", null ] } // this throws an exception
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works with schemas for Azure Logic Apps.

Comment: This solution is also recognized by Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 12):

[**anyOf**](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#id6) may also be useful.

```
"member_region": {
  "anyOf": [
    { "type": "string" },
    { "type": "null" },
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

["string", "null"] will work if you're not using a RegEx pattern.

I'm using a date field validator:

```
    (0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d
```

to allow a MM/dd/yyyy pattern, but it will throw a non-match error at an empty string ("")

Comment: An empty string is not equivalent to `null` in JSON.

Comment: Actually, I fixed this with this:

        ((0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d )*?