# JSON .Net generates schema incorrectly (type as an array)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net, jsonschema

When using the JSON.Net JsonSchemaGenerator to generate JSON Schema for my object:

```vb
Public Class Host
    Public Property uid() As String
End Class
```

It generates the type property as an array of strings:

```js
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "uid": {
            "required": true,
            "type": [
                "string",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The proper JSON Schema should be:

```js
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "uid": {
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an array of strings, it is a [nullable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241333/specify-a-value-can-be-a-string-or-null-with-json-schema).

`{ "type": [ "string", "null" ] }` means that a valus is either a string or null. Array of strings would be `{ "type": "array", "items": { "type": "string" } }`

Comment: Ah yes.  Thank you.  I cannot find any documentation (other your link) that describes the "type": ["string","null"] as a valid nullable string type.  But I'll take your word for it.

Comment: Actually, now I see the problem.  The schema is generating the "Type" as an array of types.  Is this valid JSON schema? The framework I am using is looking for a schema similar to: `    "name": {
            "title": "Name",
            "description": "Enter your full name.",
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }`  How do I change the property to a not-nullable type but with the required property set?

Comment: [Arrays in `type` are in the specification](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor79), so the generated schema looks correct. JSON Schema is currently a draft, and I'm afraid conformance of tools greatly varies. Try validating using the generated schema in JSON.NET.